# How could I know if I run MAKER with MPI(MPIch)?

Tags: annotations, mpi, hpc

I am running maker to annotation a genome.But i didn't run maker with MPI before, so the speed is very low.A genome of 300Mb last 22 days, and still running.
And i re read the manual of maker, it said support with MPI.So I installed MPI according to it.
Now the question is , how I know if it running with MPI?

the following is my slrum-script

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J MPI-test
#SBATCH -p xhacnormala
#SBATCH -N 4
#SBATCH -n 64
#SBATCH --mem 0
#SBATCH -o MPI.out
#SBATCH -e MPI.err

source /public1/home/casdao/kdylvfenghua/kdy_sy2021/maker_env
module load mpi/mpich/3.3.2/gcc-485

mpiexec -n 64 maker
```

Comment: or how can i get maker to annotations faster?

Comment: did you rebuild `maker` with MPI? If not, `mpiexec -n 64 maker` will simply run 64 times the very same serial program, and this is not what you want to do.

Comment: sure, i rebuild maker with MPI, i used MPIch 3.3.2
you can see the build status:

`STATUS MAKER v2.31.11

PERL Dependencies: VERIFIED
External Programs: VERIFIED
External C Libraries: VERIFIED
MPI SUPPORT:  ENABLED
MWAS Web Interface: DISABLED
MAKER PACKAGE:  CONFIGURATION OK`